# Magento 2 - Check if record with certain value already exist in table before creating it

Tags: magento2, database, model, table, crud

I created a new table `company_shipping_quote`.

I am writing data into it like this:

```
$quoteId = $quote->getId();
$html = $this->_generateNote($expressRule);

$quoteModel = $this->_companyShippingQuoteFactory->create();
$quoteModel->setQuoteId($quote->getId());
$quoteModel->setExpressNote($html);
$quoteModel->save();
```

But this does not check if there is already an entry with the value for `quote_id` and it just creates duplicates.

[image]

How can I check if there is already a row with that `quote_id` before creating it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below code - Another way

```
<?php

protected $_companyShippingQuoteFactory;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Company\Shipping\Model\QuoteFactory $companyShippingQuoteFactory
) {
    ...
    $this->_companyShippingQuoteFactory = $companyShippingQuoteFactory;
}

...

$quote_id =13718;

$quoteModel = $this->_companyShippingQuoteFactory->create();
$quoteModel->load($quote_id, 'quote_id');
if ($quoteModel->getId()) {
    echo "Updated";
} else {
   echo "New Added";
}
$quoteModel->save();
```

Comment: check it's different

Comment: my code is execute fast

Comment: change factory and check I have update code check. i know it's working

Comment: do not use CollectionFactory use your model factory like QuoteFactory because our code does not load all collection. it's load single only so that why it executes fast

Comment: I accept your solution, because it looks more performant and I don't need to use another class. Thx!

Comment: @Black What problem with my solution ?

Answer (score 2):

> **Try This Code**

```
protected $_companyShippingQuoteFactory;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Company\Shipping\Model\Quote\ResourceModel\CollectionFactory $companyShippingQuoteFactory
) {
    ...
    $this->_companyShippingQuoteFactory = $companyShippingQuoteFactory;
}

...

$quote_id =13718;

$quoteModel = $this->_companyShippingQuoteFactory->create();
$quoteModel->addFieldToFilter('quote_id',$quote_id)

if(count($quoteModel->getData())){
    echo "quote id added";
} else {
    echo "New quote id";
}
```

Comment: I had to use `\Company\Shipping\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\CollectionFactory $companyShippingQuoteFactory`. I generated my model with https://mage2gen.com/

Comment: The path seems to be wrong. If I generate the models from mage2gen, then it does not create a file under the path

Answer (score 2):

There might be a more straight forward solution.

If quote_id is unique in your database it makes more sense to use it as a primary key.

So you remove entity_id from db_schema.xml and change the resourceModel accordingly changing _idFieldName to quote_id. You then add this to the _construct(): (check this question [how to save data into custom table](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/324586/how-to-save-data-into-custom-table/324588#324588)):

```
$this->_isPkAutoIncrement = false;
```

Of your resource model, you then be able to change the value by code like this assuming the quoteId already exists in the database:

```
$quoteModel = $this->_companyShippingQuoteFactory->create();
$quoteModel->setQuoteId($quote->getId());
$quoteModel->setExpressNote($newHTMLhtml);
$quoteModel->save();
```

Comment: But the quote_id has to be a foreign key of the key `entity_id` in the table `quote`. I can't define it as Primary and Foreign Key at the same time.

Comment: I think it is no problem to have something as both a foreign key and a primary key, did not test in Magento though, but in mysql I think it is legal

Comment: I tested it in magento, but it just creates the PRIMARY key.

Answer (score 0):

since using model is deprecated we use this to load with specific field and save data.

we need these 4 classes to load and update or add new data

```
1. `\vendor\module\Model\testFactory $ModeltestFactor`
2. `\vendor\module\Model\ResourceModel\test $ResourceModelytest
3.`\vendor\module\Model\testRepository $ModelRepositorytest`
4.`\vendor\module\Api\Data\testInterfaceFactory $InterfaceFactorytest`
```

and in class

```
  $model = $this->ModeltestFactor->create();
  $this->ResourceModeltest->load($model,'123456','column_name');

  if ($model->getData()){
      $model->setBinTo('Bin_Code');
  }else {
      $model = $this->InterfaceFactorytest->create();
      $model->setNumber('No');
      $model->setMoveBy('jjjjj');
      $model->setItem('Item_No');
  }

  $this->ModelRepositorytest->save($model);
```

**EDIT**
or you can use only two classes

```
1. `\vendor\module\Model\testFactory $ModeltestFactor`
2. `\vendor\module\Model\ResourceModel\test $ResourceModelytest
```

and in class

```
  $model = $this->ModeltestFactor->create();
  $this->ResourceModeltest->load($model,'123456','column_name');

  if ($model->getData()){
      $model->setBinTo('Bin_Code');
  }else {
      $model->setNumber('No');
      $model->setMoveBy('jjjjj');
      $model->setItem('Item_No');
  }

  $this->ModelRepositorytest->save($model);
```